# CSS/JS Piechart doesn't go further than 180 degrees

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a pie chart using vanilla css/js. It seems to work fine for any degrees 0-180 but when i try to go over 180 degrees the rotation seems to go the wrong way. See the js fiddle:

```
<div class="pieContainer">
  <div class="pieBackground"></div>
  <div id="approvedSlice" class="hold">
    <div id="approvedSlicePie" class="pie"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  document.getElementById("approvedSlice").style.transform = 'rotate(0deg)';
  document.getElementById("approvedSlicePie").style.transform = 'rotate(305deg)';
</script>

<style>
  .pieContainer {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      top: 130px;
      padding: 6px;
      height: 40px;
  }
  .pieBackground {
      position: absolute;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      border-radius: 100%;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  }
  .pie {
      transition: all 1s;
      position: absolute;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      border-radius: 100%;
      clip: rect(0px, 20px, 40px, 0px);
  }
  .hold {
      position: absolute;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      border-radius: 100%;
      clip: rect(0px, 40px, 40px, 20px);
  }
  #approvedSlicePie {
      background-color: #0a0;
  }
</style>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/myvth518/

Comment: after 180 deg the pie chart changes with white color not green.need to check why is that.Why you didn't use chartjs.There are many options you can use

Comment: This feature is embedded in a kendo MVVM and we aren't able to use third party tools. There are many reasons behind why but to cut it short we must use vanilla CSS/JS.

Comment: https://codepen.io/dgca/pen/jwZGqv try this.Here pass the deg as a percentage

Comment: A tool that I find very helpful in these situations: If you're in chrome, right click your chart, and do *Inspect Element*. Select your element with the rotation on it, and you should see the `transform: rotate(305deg);` in the dev tools window. Click on the actual `305` portion, and hold your up/down arrows to change the value, watching how it affects the shape as you do. Repeat this with the other element as well. You should be able to experiment with this enough to modify your code and achieve your goal.

Comment: @TylerRoper yeah thats what I have been doing and what i noticed is that from 0-180 the green pie goes from north point to east to south. Then from 180-360 instead of the green pie going from south to west to north, white starts going from north to east to south (if this makes sense..). I am seeing what is happening but having hard time understanding why

Comment: Remove the clip on the 'hold' class. That should get you going in the right direction...and change the 'pie' class clip to rect(0px, 20px, 20px, 0px);

Comment: If you are OK with adding some logic and elements, then adding another pie to the `hold` after 180 deg might help and remove the `hold` clip property. So basically if it is greater than 180 deg then you move the other pie by that greater angle. Example of 220 deg pie here https://jsfiddle.net/xpcw4bkf/6/

Comment: @codisfy I was thinking about doing dual pie slices but the problem is that in the real project we have up to 5-10 slices and that gets really complex to maintain 2 slices for each.

Comment: You wouldn't have to replicate the code for each of the 5-10 slices. Just make a component(if you are using something like react) or a small function in jquery/vanilla pass it the container and the deg and it will draw the slice for you.

Comment: @codisfy I ended up using your approach and it seemed to work! thank you!

Comment: Good to know that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing 2 slices for the part that was more the 180 degrees:

```
<div class="pieContainer">
  <div class="pieBackground"></div>
</div>

<style>
    .pieContainer {
          display: inline-block;
          position: relative;
          top: 130px;
          padding: 6px;
          height: 40px;
      }
      .pieBackground {
          position: absolute;
          width: 40px;
          height: 40px;
          border-radius: 100%;
          box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      }
      .pie {
          transition: all 1s;
          position: absolute;
          width: 40px;
          height: 40px;
          border-radius: 100%;
          clip: rect(0px, 20px, 40px, 0px);
      }
      .hold {
          position: absolute;
          width: 40px;
          height: 40px;
          border-radius: 100%;
          clip: rect(0px, 40px, 40px, 20px);
      }
</style>


<script>
    GeneratePieSlice('#0a0', 'firstSlice', 0, 200);
    GeneratePieSlice('#1d0eff', 'secondSlice', 200, 100);
    GeneratePieSlice('#aa0000', 'thirdSlice', 300, 60);



    function GeneratePieSlice(color, baseName, startPoint, length){

      CreatePieRelatedDivs(color, baseName);

      if (length <= 180) {
        document.getElementById(baseName).style.transform = `rotate(${startPoint}deg)`;
        document.getElementById(baseName + "pie").style.transform = `rotate(${length}deg)`;
        return;
      } else {  
        CreatePieRelatedDivs(color, baseName, true);
        var pie1Start = startPoint;
        var pie1End = 180;

        var pie2Start = pie1Start + 180;
        var pie2End = length - 180;

        document.getElementById(baseName).style.transform = `rotate(${pie1Start}deg)`;
        document.getElementById(baseName + "pie").style.transform = `rotate(${pie1End}deg)`;

        document.getElementById(baseName + "2").style.transform = `rotate(${pie2Start}deg)`;
        document.getElementById(baseName + "pie2").style.transform = `rotate(${pie2End}deg)`;
        return;
      }
    }


    function CreatePieRelatedDivs(color, baseName, helper = false){
      var approvedSliceId = "";
      var pieId = "";

      if (!helper){
        approvedSliceId = baseName;
        pieId = baseName + "pie";
      } else {
        approvedSliceId = baseName + "2";
        pieId = baseName + "pie2";  
      }


      var approvedSlice = document.createElement("div");
      approvedSlice.id = approvedSliceId;
      approvedSlice.className = "hold";

      var pie = document.createElement("div");
      pie.id = pieId;
      pie.className = "pie";  
      pie.style = `background-color: ${color}`;

      $('.pieContainer').append(approvedSlice);
      $(`#${approvedSliceId}`).append(pie);

    }
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/myvth518/133/